# How do I play as a Ro-Bro in all levels? ('Later Ro-bros!' achievement)

Tags: pc, achievements, double-dragon-neon

I'm playing the PC / Steam version of Double Dragon Neon. I [searched cheat codes for it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=double%20dragon%20neon%20cheats) and learned that there is a [cheat code where I could play as a Ro-Bro](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/666512-double-dragon-neon/cheats) in any level, however the button combinations I can find are for the console versions of the game. This cheat code is also required, AFAIK, to get the [*Later Ro-bros!* achievement (beat every level as a Ro-bro)](https://www.achievementstats.com/index.php?action=games&achievementId=54603).

Does anyone know the equivalent keyboard keys for the PC version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remap keyboard keys to the equivalent controller buttons needed to activate the Ro-Bro cheat code. However, the [2014-02-28 update](http://steamcommunity.com/games/252350/announcements/detail/1657627503987663968?l=english) now allows keyboard players to enable Ro-Bro mode. Related changelog:

> Added an option in the Settings menu so that mouse and keyboard players have a way to enable Ro-Bro Mode.